# How to calculate center of gravity of pixels in an image?

Tags: matlab

This is my homework question:

Write `HW3_func.m` as follows:

- `function [cogR, cogC] = HW3_func ( f, i )`
- `f`: input grayscale image
- `i` : intensity level to check
- Function should find all the pixels in `f` with intensity of `i`. Then, return the center of gravity of those pixels as `[cogR, cogC]`.  Center of gravity is computed as the average of the row and average of column.  If no `pixel == i`, then return `[0,0]`

I don't understand how to calculate center of gravity. What I have done is:

1. Declare a matrix `X` with the same dimension as the image. Initialize it with all zeros
2. Find the position of the pixels with the given intensity in the input image and replace those positions in `X` with `1`.

Am I on the right path?

This is what I have right now:

```
function [ cogR,cogC ] = HW3_func(f,i)

    [r,c] = size(f)
    X = zeros(r,c)
    for k = 1:r
        for j = 1:c
            if f(k,j)==i
               X(k,j)=1;
            end        
        end
    end

    %disp(X)

    cogR=centroid(X);
    cogC=centroid(X,2);

    disp(cogR)
    disp(cogC)

end
```

Comment: Your code so far is good enough, except for proper formatting. The center of gravity is the average coordinate, weighted with the density (in your case the density is 1 or 0). So in essence, use a formula for the "weighted mean", using the row index as data and the (1 or 0) as weight to get the cogR. I don't know what the goal of the course is, so getting rid of the loops may be overkill or it may be the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just want to use `find()`, e.g.

```
[row_indices, col_indices, values] = find(f==i)
```

The CoG coordinates are then, as you said, just the average of the row and column indices, which you now have in two vectors. See `mean()`.

Comment: Have I got the answer? I mean ..should I just return cogR and cogC and will that complete the answer?

Comment: @Nikhil `cogR = mean(row_indices); cogC = mean(col_indices);`.